# How to store the values passed by one jsp page into another variable in another jsp

Tags: jsp

I am retrieving the values from one jsp into another jsp through

```
<%=request.getParameter("Propertyname")%>
```

I passed the value inside another variable in the requested page by the following code:

```
<%String arguments=<%=request.getParameter("Propertyname")%>;%>
```

how to solve this,is there any convenient way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this to put values from one page into the request so a common bit of JSP can use them. In this case the title of the page:

```
<c:set var="pageName" scope="request" value="Home" />
```

and at the other jsp's end

```
<title><c:out value="${pageName}" /></title>
```

This is using JSTL, which is a bit more tag-based than your "java in angle brackets" example.